# How to make Unity top panel semi-transparent?

Tags: unity

How do I make the top bar on the screen semi-transparent, like the launcher on the left?

[image: Screenshot of top bar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could install **CompizConfig Settings Manager** (**CCSM**) to accomplish that.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

After installation, open your dash and type `ccsm`.

Use the search filter to find the `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`. Under *Experimental* tab, go to *Panel Opacity* and reduce the value until transparency is to your liking.

That's it, you're done!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Compiz, for example if you use Metacity, perhaps it would be simpler just to use Unity-Tweak-Tool, go to Unity>Panel, and turn down the opacity there.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`